# how can I write R code to create a new column returning the most frequent item of a list column for every row in the dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, frequency

current code is shown below. I am trying to return the most common element of a a list (column 12 in the `df`) in a new column (`df$newCol`) for every row of the dataframe. Column 12 in `df`, of type `list` is titled `df$status_combined` and has values that look like this: `c("high", " medium", " medium")`

```
for (index in 1:nrow(df)) {
  row = df[index, ]
  df$newCol <- names(sort(list.table(as.vector(df[row,12])), decreasing = TRUE))[1]
}

Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Comment: I don't know what `list.table` is nor what you think `as.vector(df[row,12])` is supposed to be doing. It might help if you provide perspective, including sample data (with `dput(head(df))` and expected output.

Comment: Please edit your question to put the data there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your description that `df$status_combined` is a `list` like "L" created below:

```
set.seed(1)
L <- replicate(5, sample(c("high", "medium", "low"), 10, TRUE), FALSE)
```

You're not far off in terms of your approach. I'd suggest a simple function like the following:

```
f <- function(x) names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))[1]
```

You can then get your result by simply doing:

```
sapply(L, f)
# [1] "medium" "low"    "high"   "low"    "low"
```

If you wanted the tabulation of all values, you can try something like:

```
table(rev(stack(setNames(L, seq_along(L)))))
#    values
# ind high low medium
#   1    3   3      4
#   2    2   5      3
#   3    4   2      4
#   4    2   4      4 ## <~~ You'll have to think about ties
#   5    1   5      4
```